# Sublime Text + Evince problem

Tags: forward-inverse-search, sublime-text, evince

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Sublimetext 3 and I want to use forward and inverse search for latex files. Everything (compilation, forward and inverse search) works perfectly fine, except if I have a tex (and corresponding pdf) file starting with a number, such as

9.tex

For such files, forward and inverse search don't work. How to fix the settings in this case?

Comment: Hi, Can you add a MWE, please with a screenshot?

Comment: I downloaded the most recent version of latexing, and now it works. Thanks.